# How to import mp3 file in TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, import, mp3, usesound

I'm working on a web app using React and TypeScript.
Right now, I'm trying to import mp3 file to use for use-sound, but the TypeScript gives me:

"Cannot find module '../../assets/sounds/sample1.mp3' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)"

Anyone knows how to fix this?
In below, I have the code from the use-sound document to describe my issue.

```
import useSound from 'use-sound';
import s1 from '../../assets/sounds/sample1.mp3'; // <- this gives me the error

const BoopButton = () => {
  const [play] = useSound(s1);

  return <button onClick={play}>Boop!</button>;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you add types for this? Try npm install @types/use-sound

Comment: I ran npm i use-sound and there is types.d.ts file in node_module/use-sound/dist directory.

Comment: To be honest, I don't think it's to do with the use-sound, but to do with TypeScript's declaration rules.

Comment: I think I fixed it by adding a @types directory in the src and then add new file called audio.d.ts (src/@types/audio.d.ts). Inside the audio.d.ts, I wrote "declare module '*.mp3';", and that fixed the importing issue. Thanks boki_bo